# Inheriting static methods in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm generating TypeScript classes that use Inheritance. Each of the Classes uses a static create-function, which may be different.

```
class A {
  static create(arg: string): A {
    // use args to create A
    return new A()
  };
} 

class B extends A {
  static create(argsForB: number): B {
    // use argsForB to create B
    return new B()
  };
}
```

Since static functions should not be inherited anyway, this Error does not make any sense:

```
Class static side 'typeof B' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof A'.
  Types of property 'create' are incompatible.
    Type '(argsForB: number) => B' is not assignable to type '(arg: string) => A'.
      Types of parameters 'argsForB' and 'arg' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

I know one solution would be to simply rename the create-funtion to createA and createB, but it does not feel right.

Comment: *"Since static functions should not be inherited anyway"* - I don't think that's correct. From an OOP perspective it doesn't make sense to have to care which specific subclass of `A` you have in order to call its `create` method correctly, that breaks the substitution principle. `static create(argsForB: string): B` would be fine, because it still meets the fundamental contract in the parent.

Comment: "*Since static functions should not be inherited anyway*" - but they are. `B` does literally inherit prototypically from `A`. Having one `create` method take a number and the other a string does violate the [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: I understand the substitution-pattern, but static-functions are not part of the object. They are only attached to the constructor-function and not to the prototype and always refeferenced with the qualified name:
`A.create()` or `B.create()`.

Comment: In java for example, this would compile without any error. 
funny enough even the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20create(arg%3A%20string)%3A%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20use%20args%20to%20create%20A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20A()%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20create(argsForB%3A%20number)%3A%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20use%20argsForB%20to%20create%20B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20B()%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D) generates correct javascript-output.

Comment: @simonjentzsch Indeed. In native JavaScript, this works fine. The `static method()` in the derived class successfully overrides the `static method()` in the base class. I'm not sure why TypeScript requires that methods of the same name in base and derived classes share the same types. It's the same for non-static methods. However, if the method in the derived class has zero arguments, TypeScript is fine with it. This can be seen in the TypeScript Playground, but the link is too long to share here. Have you considered raising this issue in the GitHub repository? The behaviour seems quite odd.

Comment: i think is because the fact of if somewhere you do `this.constructor.create()` its should same everywhere to avoid ambiguity ! maybe, btw , it a ugly rule for ts

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Typescript is mainly a superset of recent ECMAscript rules. Generally speaking, Javascript does not have types, thus Typescript is preventing you from creating a class for which it thinks Javascript will be unable to discern which version you mean to call. It cannot enforce execution of one version or the other because the generated code is the same for both, from the TS perspective. Also note that this has nothing to do with the methods being static. If you remove the static qualifier you will get an error on the create method of the second class with a similar message.

Take a look at the generated typescript on the Playground and you see what it means: [Typescript Playground example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20create(arg%3A%20string)%3A%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20use%20args%20to%20create%20A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20A()%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20create(argsForB%3A%20number)%3A%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20use%20argsForB%20to%20create%20B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20B()%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D)

I still don't quite understand what you aim to do in this instance, but doing something like this will remove the issue, albeit probably not solve what you are trying to get done:

```
class A {
  static create(arg: string | number): A {
    // use args to create A
    return new A()
  };
} 

class B extends A {
  static create(argsForB: string | number): B {
    // use argsForB to create B
    return new B()
  };
}
```

There are many constructs that work fine in Javascript, that Typescript calls out as errors because the way they work does not allow for enforcement of the type rules.

Consider the following:

```
class A {
  content: string;
  static create(arg: string): A {
    // use args to create A
    let result = new A();
    result.content = arg;
    return new A()
  };
} 

class B extends A {
  content: number;
  static create(argsForB: number): B {
    // use argsForB to create B
    let result = new B();
    result.content = argsForB;
    return result;
  };
  sendMessage
}

let testB = B.create(5);
alert(testB.content);
let testCastA = testB as A;
alert(testCastA.content);
```

As before, Javascript is generated that makes this work, but it does not do what I would expect.

Comment: "but it does not do what I would expect" can you clarify what you would expect it to do?

Comment: What I meant is that if you run the generated JavaScript code, the last call returns "undefined". In other words, the generated code looks like it would do the casting but in reality it does not. Thus TypeScript warning / error is correct (nowadays the error is displayed slightly different).